# Can HTTP get download excel (xls) file on my local computer but not on EC2 or remote lambda. EC2 Security Group is ok

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, curl

I've encountered a simple yet strange problem. I am just trying to download this file programmatically through HTTP get.

```
https://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/Silver_stocks.xls
```

On my local computer, wget works, curl works, javascript works, java works. Works on my local AWS Lambda invocation.

On the remote EC2 Linux, EC2 Windows, and Lambda, none of these things work for that one url. It works for other urls like Target.com.

The security group is configured so I can ssh in and all outbound traffic is allowed.

A basic curl command won't work on your local computer. Use this.

```
curl 'https://www.cmegroup.com/delivery_reports/Silver_stocks.xls' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
--compressed \
--output testtest.xls
```

On EC2 Windows, you can download the file through a browser.

I'm guessing the server has some extra security?

What is going on?

Comment: Is your domain handled by Route53 and Route53 Outbound DNS Resolver? Similar issues I had, if the domain was handled by Route53 of another account and the Outbound Resolver sends those requests to the wrong DNS. If this is not the case, how is the routing table defined? Probably differenct CIDR ranges are routed to another location (private subnet/public subnet) etc.

Comment: I don't use Route 53. Routing table for this subnet is: 
10.0.0.0/16, target: local, status: Active, propagated: No 
0.0.0.0/0, target: internet gateway, status: active, propagated: no 
Nothing looks out of the ordinary.